# Morris js dynamic ykeys

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, morris.js

I am building a chart to track my product stocks on how many do I have left in a month. I'm trying to build a 12-month projected stock from the current month.

I would like to give a try [Morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/). In there [demo](http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output) you have `a` and `b` as your `ykeys`. I assume those are products. It works great if you have control of your product list. But what if the your user added new products. Say, product `c`, `d` and `e`. How do you intend to those product in the chart without hard-coding it?

I'm using asp.net mvc 5, EF 4 Code-first. I can't get in my head on how to achieve it. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I find a solution for mvc : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347282/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-sharp/33371447#33371447

Comment: I opt to use reflection to create my classes runtime and have it populated with my data. Thanks. I'll try that one out.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an array of values that is fetched dynamically for your ykeys attribute.  How this array is fetched is really up to you, but one possibility is via an Ajax request.  Consider the following:

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: getGraphDataUrl,
   type: "GET",
   statusCode: {
        200: function (msg) {
            if(typeof msg != 'undefined' && msg.length > 0) {
                msg = JSON.parse(msg);
                Morris.Line({
                    element: 'line-example',
                    data: msg.data,
                    xkey: 'y',
                    ykeys: msg.ykeys,
                    labels: msg.labels
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Clearly, this is a grossly simplified example.  As you can see, many attributes could be fetched as JSON via an Ajax request.  Of course, you will have to write the server-side code that will form the JSON response, but I believe that is outside of the scope of this question.